# Launch image adds margin

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, uistoryboard

After adding my launch image using a xib (and I even tried the traditional launch image way as well) some of my view controllers have a strange right margin now. For example before I might have had a label whose width was the entire screen, and used auto layouts such that it was leading/trailing to the content margins, and now despite that after adding a launch image there is a margin (it's not on every screen, but definitely some). On one of my screens where this is most prevalent i'm using autolayout but overriding with constraints that I add programmatically. Not sure if that's related.

Has anyone experienced anything like this or does anyone know if adding launch screens affect the story board / view controllers in any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the **launch screen select your image view**, then select the **pin at the bottom right** of xcode (3rd option). Make sure all constraints are **set to 0**, while making sure the red I is selected for each one when they are set and **uncheck constraint to margins**. Finally click **add constraints** :)

Hope this helps you!

Rachel